# Editing apache2.config with PHP

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

Can't edit **apache2.conf** with php, I create this code above and doesn't work :

```
$path_apache = '/home/user/conf/web/exemple.com.apache2.conf';
if (file_exists($path_apache)){
    $content_apache = file_get_contents($path_apache);
    $content_apache = str_replace('DocumentRoot /home/user/web/to_replace/public_html', 'DocumentRoot /home/user/web/to_replace_with/public_html',$content_apache);
    file_put_contents($path_apache, $content_apache);
}
```

I can edit file with SSH but for PHP the file doesn't exist. I edit Virtual Host with this and still can't edit file config :

```
<Directory /home/user/conf/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir /home/user/conf/web:/home/user/tmp
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/user/tmp
    php_admin_value session.save_path /home/user/tmp
</Directory>
```

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking. Are you trying to edit your apache.conf file using php? If that is what you're doing, you should probably NOT be doing it.

Comment: I think this falls under the XY Problem (http://xyproblem.info/) realm.

Comment: I gave a lot more information, yes i like to edit my apache.conf file.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. Error messages are. Actively look for them.